# StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden' when doing prediction request in google ml in .net

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I am currently working to make the prediction request using the library : Google.Apis.CloudMachineLearningEngine.v1 and ended up with a JSON return :

```
{
StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: 
System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Referer
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: private
Date: Mon, 13 Aug 2018 17:57:44 GMT
Server: ESF
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
}
}.
```

My code is similar with this [blog](http://tylerfindlay.com/net-core-googlecloudmlv1predictrequest-execture-method-returns-null-response/). (the last code he made)

I also have an editor role set up for that service account, (changed in IAM & ADMIN/IAM) and also added editor permission on ML Engine/Models/{model name} to that generated email.

I want to know if there is something I missed. I am running the code in asp.net in debug mode (via localhost). I just need a bit of clear information to make it work.

Comment: If the service account associated with the key has editor role on the project, then you should be able to do prediction. Have you tried prediction using  gcloud ml-engine predict  just to cross verify.  You can also try granting ML Engine Developer role to the service account.

Comment: 403 error is related with service account permission related errors. Can you verify if you are following the steps as [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-training-prediction#set-up-your-gcp-project) and setting up the authentication accordingly?